# How only average cells that cell to the left contains a number

Tags: excel, average

I need formula help
using cells a1 - ce1,  various data, but about every 3rd to 5th column is a column containing a %.  I need to average by row, the % but only if the cell to the left contains a number(even 0).

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the problem. Please provide an example of your data, and the expected output.  Please read the HELP pages for information about [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula `AVERAGEIF()` to achieve this. You can find further information on its use here: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php

Comment: How is that used to detect if a value is a `%`?

Comment: Not sure if you could unless you can assume that all % numbers are between 0 and 1 but regardless I took the question to only restrict average if the cell to the left is empty not to determine if the number itself is formatted as percentage.